error on images inserted in one column
I have a two column layout. I want insert two images as subfigures align next to each other, spanning one column.
How to solve this error?
Overfull \hbox (247.6778pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 79--79
Paragraph ended before \Gin@ii was complete.
Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }.
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
% Some Computer Society conferences also require the compsoc mode option,
% but others use the standard conference format.
%
% If IEEEtran.cls has not been installed into the LaTeX system files,
% manually specify the path to it like:
% \documentclass[conference]{../sty/IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{algorithm}


%\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{ifpdf}
 
 

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ifCLASSINFOpdf
 
\else
  
\fi


% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
%\usepackage{stfloats}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic,lipsum}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{natbib}

%\usepackage{draftwatermark}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
    \newtheorem{question}{Question}[section]
    \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
    \newtheorem{scheme}{Scheme}

\newcommand{\Switch}[1]{\STATE \textbf{switch} #1 \textbf{do}}
%\newcommand{\Case}[2]{\STATE \hspace{\algorithmicindent}\textbf{case} #1: #2}
\newcommand{\EndSwitch}{\STATE \textbf{end switch}}



\usepackage[width=0.48\textwidth]{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\subfigcapmargin = 2em

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h!t]
    \centering
    \subfloat[ELLL:3444(45),CR=6661]{\includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{f1.png}}~
    \subfloat[JPPP:3444(54),CR=67663]{\includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{f1.png}}\\
    \subfloat[ELLLL:3444(145,CR=999]{\includegraphics[width = 1.8in {f1.png}}~
    \subfloat[JPPP:3444(154),CR=777]{\includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{f1.png}}\\
      \subfloat[ELLL:3444(340),CR=1444]{\includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{f1.png}}~
    \subfloat[JPPP:3444(340),CR=1323]{\includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{f1.png}}\\
    \caption{The caption.}
    \label{fig7}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


'Overfull \hbox' is not an error, it is a warning! You should still get an output PDF.

Your example gives ! LaTeX Error: Command \c@subfigure already defined. in texlive 2024

If you have any other issues, please provide us with a complete MWE. Please don't post full code fragments. It's much easier for people to help you if you provide at least one compilable (even with errors) minimal document.

don't load subfig and subfigure

@codeR, yes, it load the pdf but its not the desired output

@DavidCarlisle, the same output

what has the same output as what? The point of my comment is that you are asking about an error on image inclusion but you post an example that stops with an unrelated error before reaching the \includegraphics. please clarify the question.

the error on \includegraphics is because you omitted the ] in \includegraphics[width = 1.8in {f1.png} which should be \includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{f1.png}

@DavidCarlisle, Thank you so much, I did not noticed that!

Your example is far from minimal (do not load conflicting packages such as subfig and subfigure at the same time, don't specify lipsum three times...
A simpler example is
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width = 1.8in {example-image.png}

\end{document}

which produces
Runaway argument?
width = 1.8in {example-image.png} 
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@ii was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.7 
    
?

due to the missing ] which should close the optional argument.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{example-image.png}

\end{document}

